# How to create new window in mobile devices via qml?

Tags: ios, qt, qml

**Background:**
I am trying to create a cross platform application using qt.

**Solution** **I** **found:**

```
        MouseArea {
            id: toOtherViewClicked
            width: 44
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("listOfMaterials.qml")
                var window = component.createObject("secondQML")
                window.show()
            }
        }
```

**The** **Problem**
It acts really weird. window shows up for a few minutes, but then it goes back to main window again. Is it possible to present new window opening in a proper way?

Comment: Please provide a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, do you see any error messages when the window disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should log the `Component.onDestruction()`

Most likely the `GarbageCollector` wipes your window, as you have no parent set.
The right syntax for `component.createObject()` takes an object (parent) as first argument. You pass a string instead. If you pass an object, chances are good, that the `GarbageCollector` wont wipe your newly created window, until the parent-object is destroyed.

Make it something like:

```
var window = component.createObject(toOtherViewClicked)
```

Comment: that makes sense, thank you! But in this case "toOtherViewClicked" is id of a mouseArea, shouldn't I send an id of a window?

Comment: That is up to you. If you have an id of a window at hand, why not. The only requirement is, that the object, referenced by the id outlives the created second window.